# Bios recognizes SSD but doesn't boot from it after bios update

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, crash, hard-drive-failure

I have updated the bios because my pc going through some stuff right now (like not recognizing my nvme ssd, can't update windows and boot really slow). Just before I updated the bios I chose to save my old bios version on my OS SATA SSD. Now it can't boot from the ssd automatically and it shows me the following message:[image: Error which comes up by booting automatically]

However I still see the SSD is recognized in the bios and if I choose to boot from an empty square I manage to boot from the ssd manualy. Any ideas on how to fix that?[image: The SSD is still recognized by the BIOS]
[image]

(I can't add the ssd to the boot options though).
[image: can't add the ssd to boot options]

Comment: Can you start in BIOS and then, if so, reset BIOS to Defaults, save, exit, restart and see if it starts properly.

Comment: What do you mean start in bios? I don't have a problem going to bios by just clicking Del. I have already tried getting the bios to default settings by pressing F7 and it didn't solve the problem unfortunately :(.

Comment: I am not sure. I have seen the top message on my own Desktop, and reset BIOS to defaults got me going. I will keep looking around.

Comment: thanks very much:)

Comment: While I try to look, please post back the model of the PC.

Comment: Its a gigabyte motherboard GA-B150M-D3H DDR3-CF Its got the latest bios for that particular motherboard.

Comment: Please see whether this thread helps you:  https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/ga-b150m-d3h-and-its-m-2-slot.2844413/

Comment: Your question is kind of messy. The boot menu shows the SATA SSD, does it have an OS / bootloader installed and if so, does the boot option get anything to boot up when you click on it? Are you trying to boot from the SATA SSD or the NVMe SSD after all?

Comment: The nvme isnt recognized at all, the sata ssd is there coz of that even though both hard drives have OS. I can get instead of the bios to a boot menu where the sata ssd is shown by an empty option in which I can boot into. I am asking specifically about the sata ssd since I think that me saving the bios version on it is the cause of the problem But nothing in the bios. And thx very much for you guys helping me.